# to make icon to equal width

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Basically I want to resize my button all together to one size on click operation in Javafx.

```
@FXML
private void OnClickResize(ActionEvent event) {
    VBox vBox = new VBox();

    vBox.setPrefWidth(300);

    //Button btn1 = new Button("Short");
    //Button btn2 = new Button("Super Long Button");

    btn_preview.setMaxWidth(vBox.getPrefWidth());
    btn_pdf_preview.setMaxWidth(vBox.getPrefWidth());
    btn_bilingualfile.setMaxWidth(vBox.getPrefWidth());

    btn_close.setMaxWidth(vBox.getPrefWidth());

    vBox.getChildren().addAll(btn_preview,btn_pdf_preview,btn_bilingualfile,btn_close);
}
```

But this is for vbox and vbox is of no use for me, so I want such kind of solution of tabpane in javafx .

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do. Providing a code that looks like the method of a `ActionEvent` handler of an unknown `Node` isn't telling a lot. Creating a `VBox` in the handler method and adding children to it, then throwing this `VBox` away isn't going to tell us what you are trying to do either.

Comment: see, first of all ignore vbox case as i am just giving the example through vbox ,there is a fxml page in my project and and all the buttons on that page is under tabpane ,so what i want by click event i want to get the same size of button like if small all the button should  reduce the size or if large all the buttons should become large .

Comment: It is still very unclear. Does all your buttons have the same size in the first place? If they are the same size, what did you do to make them the same size? Are they the same size because you hard-coding the same size? "Small" button is supposed to reduce size or set all of them to a particular size (e.g. 30px x 15px) that is small? Do you have somewhere with the references of every single button?

Comment: see,right now all my buttons are of different size and what i want when i click "Small" button ,it should set all of them to a particular size and the size should be smaller with reference to their current size and not only on one page there are 3-4 fxml page integrated to each other ,basically it should set button to the small size for the whole project..i hope now i'm clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be very easy and elegant to implement, but you can try it out. You need some kind of a singleton class. You can change the actual singleton implementation if you need it to be thread-safe etc.

```
public class ButtonSizeManager {
    private ButtonSizeManager instance;

    private ButtonSizeManager() {}

    public static final ButtonSizeManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new ButtonSizeManager();

        return instance;
    }

    private static final double LARGE_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final double LARGE_HEIGHT = 30;
    /* Similar constants for medium and small sizes */

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper width = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(); 
    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper height = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();

    public final void largeSize() {
        width.set(LARGE_WIDTH);
        height.set(LARGE_WIDTH);
    }

    /* Similar methods for medium and small */

    public final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty widthProperty() {
        return width.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
    public final double getWidth() { this.width.get(); }

    public final ReadOnlyDoubleProperty heightProperty() {
        return height.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
    public final double getHeight() { this.height.get(); }
}
```

Then all your buttons (yes, this will be tedious) will have to bind to this. That means if you have buttons created from FXML, then you need to give them `fx:id` in FXML and get their injected reference in the controller class.

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML private Button foo;

    public void initialize() {
        foo.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        foo.setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        foo.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        foo.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        foo.prefWidthProperty.bind(ButtonSizeManager.getInstance().widthProperty());
        foo.prefHeightProperty.bind(ButtonSizeManager.getInstance().heightProperty());
    }
}
```

If you do not want to do so much for each button, then you can move some of the codes into `ButtonSizeManager`.

```
public final bindButtonSize(Button button) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(button);

    button.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    button.setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    button.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

    button.prefWidthProperty.bind(widthProperty());
    button.prefHeightProperty.bind(heightProperty());
}
```

To change size, simply call the method in the singleton class (e.g. `ButtonSizeManager.largeSize()`)

Comment: @PragatiSingh Make that static. It's supposed to be singleton

Comment: @PragatiSingh It's typo, `prefWidthProperty` is supposed to be method. `getInstance()` is a method, it's not even a class. You need to build up your fundamentals on JavaFX.

Comment: @PragatiSingh Just do it in a separate java file. Singletons are supposed to be visibly to all.

Comment: @PragatiSingh I'm already telling you, don't force it into the same class. **Move it to a separate file.**

Answer (score 0):

You could add a style class to the root name depending on the size and use a CSS stylesheet to modify the size of the buttons e.g. by modifying the `-fx-font-size` property:

#### style.css

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
    combo.getItems().addAll("small", "medium", "large");
    combo.setValue("medium");

    VBox root = new VBox(combo);
    root.getStyleClass().add("medium");

    combo.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        root.getStyleClass().removeAll(combo.getItems());
        root.getStyleClass().add(newValue);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        root.getChildren().add(new Button("button " + i));
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

```css
.small .button {
    -fx-font-size: 8;
}

.medium .button {
}

.large .button {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
}
```

There are also properties available for many of a `Button`'s properties, [see *JavaFX CSS Reference Guide*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button). However note that those values won't be applied, if you set a property via inline CSS (`Node.style`) or set the corresponding property from code (e.g. `Button.setPrefWidth`).

Comment: fabian can i get your email id or something as am really having some doubts in my project and its urgent?